# Place element at bottom of the visible part of the document element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I would like to place a popup at the bottom of the visible part of an Html document, even if I scroll down?

The html document does not fit in the window so I have to scroll down to view it all. And each time I scroll, the visible part is varies. So how can I get the coordinates of the bottom of the currently visible part?

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,

Horace

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `position: fixed` on your CSS? It's supposed to position elements relative to the viewport as you want. Something like this:

```
#myelement {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS style `position: fixed;` to position the element relative to the view port (window area).

Example:

```
<div style="position:fixed;left:100px;bottom:0;width:100px;height:50p;">
  Bottom
</div>
```

Note: Some really old browsers (e.g. Internet Explorer 6) doesn't support `position: fixed`. If you need to support those, you would need to use Javascript to get the size of the window, and use `position: absolute` to place the element, and catch the `scroll` event so that you can move the element to keep it visible.